# Xml schema datatype with preserved whitespace and attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing an Xml schema where I want an element that has some attributes as a complexType and a simpleContent based on string. I wanted it to also preserve whitespace. Right now I have this snippet:

```
<xs:complexType name="actualType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="stringWithSpace">
      <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:attribute name="b" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="stringWithSpace">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The question is, do I need to have two separate types to get the attributes and the preserved whitespace or is there something I missed?

Comment: Does your current implementation work?

Comment: Yeah it currently works. It just feels really weird to both restrict and extend the string type because the only "restriction" I want is for the parser to not eat all the whitespace. It feels wrong coming from a programming background where I would extend a base type just once for one set of changes.

Comment: Your (correct) approach appears to be the standard way of doing this.  Assuming you can reuse the whitespace preserved string, I don't see this as being so bad.

Comment: It's not that I find anything bad with this method, it's just very verbose and different from what I'm used to. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing confirmation that this is just the standard way to do this as expressed in the question's original snippet. I'm answering the question so anyone who searches for this later can receive the same confirmation.